# R - Matching columns in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe

I have this NDVI timeseries dataset where the first column is dates and the next three are NDVI data for three different IDs (59231, 158157, 282302)

```
    Date X59231 X158157 X282302
1  13149     NA   0.398      NA
2  13157  0.344   0.267   0.327
3  13165     NA   0.431      NA
.  .....  .....   .....   .....
```

Here's the dput:

```
structure(list(Date = c(13149L, 13157L, 13165L, 13173L, 13181L, 
13189L, 13197L, 13205L, 13213L, 13221L, 13229L, 13237L, 13245L, 
13253L, 13261L, 13269L, 13277L, 13285L, 13293L, 13301L, 13309L, 
13317L, 13325L, 13333L, 13341L, 13349L, 13357L, 13365L, 13373L, 
13381L, 13389L, 13397L, 13405L, 13413L, 13421L, 13429L, 13437L, 
13445L, 13453L, 13461L, 13469L, 13477L, 13485L, 13493L, 13501L, 
13509L), X59231 = c(NA, 0.344, NA, 0.398, NA, 0.587, NA, NA, 
0.451, 0.597, 0.593, 0.556, 0.559, 0.375, 0.374, 0.386, 0.425, 
0.383, 0.349, 0.315, 0.282, 0.323, 0.315, 0.359, 0.292, 0.271, 
0.297, 0.307, 0.322, 0.344, 0.297, 0.285, 0.273, 0.282, 0.281, 
0.304, 0.314, NA, 0.391, 0.601, 0.65, NA, 0.653, 0.666, 0.519, 
0.625), X158157 = c(0.398, 0.267, 0.431, NA, 0.36, 0.434, 0.434, 
0.465, 0.447, 0.521, 0.539, 0.563, 0.595, 0.541, 0.553, 0.381, 
0.533, 0.505, 0.551, NA, 0.546, 0.535, 0.523, 0.501, 0.508, 0.51, 
0.506, 0.51, 0.514, 0.526, 0.555, 0.545, 0.53, 0.539, 0.531, 
0.53, NA, 0.585, 0.597, 0.32, 0.569, 0.601, NA, NA, 0.52, 0.532
), X282302 = c(NA, 0.327, NA, 0.282, 0.26, 0.293, 0.25, 0.288, 
0.336, 0.299, 0.29, 0.28, NA, 0.305, 0.319, NA, 0.255, 0.292, 
0.294, NA, NA, 0.367, 0.331, 0.344, 0.283, 0.284, 0.291, 0.273, 
0.239, 0.285, 0.249, 0.285, 0.247, 0.288, 0.276, NA, 0.317, 0.375, 
0.38, 0.417, 0.374, 0.491, NA, NA, NA, 0.471)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-46L))
```

I run the following code to smooth the timeseries (get rid of noise) and find the multiple maxs and mins for each ID's NDVI timeseries.

```
rm(list=ls())

#Read in csv data
df=read.csv("Data.csv", header = TRUE)
date_col = df[,1]

num_cols = length(df[1,]) #count number of columns there are
num_Dcols = num_cols-1 #count the number of columns there are minus the index (first) column


#Function to append columns to a dataframe
cbind.fill <- function(...){
  nm <- list(...) 
  nm <- lapply(nm, as.matrix)
  n <- max(sapply(nm, nrow)) 
  do.call(cbind, lapply(nm, function (x) 
    rbind(x, matrix(, n-nrow(x), ncol(x))))) 
}

#Create an empty data frame
finalDF = data.frame(matrix(ncol=(0),nrow=0)) #create empty dataframe

#Create an empty vector for column names
CNames = c()

for (i in c(1:num_Dcols)){
  df_sub = df[,c(1,i+1)] #create a data frame of the date column and the i+1 column

  df_removeNA = na.omit(df_sub)

  #Append the date column to the final data frame
  df_date = df_removeNA[,1]
  finalDF = cbind.fill(finalDF, df_date)

  #Append the NDVI timeseries column to the final data frame
  df_data = df_removeNA[,2]
  finalDF = cbind.fill(finalDF, df_data)


  stl_1=stl(ts(df_data, frequency=4), "periodic")

  #Function to calculate all the maximums
  ts_max<-function(signal)
  {
    points_max=which(diff(sign(diff(signal)))==-2)+1
    return(points_max)
  }

  #Function to calculate all the minimums
  ts_min<-function(signal)
  {
    points_min=which(diff(sign(diff(-signal)))==-2)+1
    return(points_min)
  }

  #Smooth the timeseries
  trend_1=as.numeric(stl_1$time.series[,2])

  #Find max and mins of the smoothed timeseries
  max_1=ts_max(trend_1)
  min_1=ts_min(trend_1)

  #Append max and mins to the final data frame
  finalDF = cbind.fill(finalDF, df_data[max_1])
  finalDF = cbind.fill(finalDF, df_data[min_1])

  #Append column names to the column names vector
  CNames = c(CNames, toString(colnames(df_sub[1])))
  CNames = c(CNames, toString(colnames(df_sub[2])))
  CNames = c(CNames, paste(c(toString(colnames(df_sub[2])), "_Max"), collapse=''))
  CNames = c(CNames, paste(c(toString(colnames(df_sub[2])), "_Min"), collapse=''))

  #Plot final results
  plot(df_date, trend_1, type = 'l')
  abline(v=df_date[max_1], col="red")
  abline(v=df_date[min_1], col="blue")
}

#Rename final data frame's column names
colnames(finalDF) = CNames

#Export final data frame to CSV
write.csv(finalDF, file = "finalDF_smooth.csv")
```

Here's an image of all the maxs and mins for the first column of NDVI timeseries data.
[image]
What I'm trying to figure out is how to add two new columns into the original (or new) data frame next to each ID column where I can store the maximums and minimums. The maximums and minimums need to be placed in the cell that matches its corresponding date. In other words, I need two duplicated columns of each ID column. Inserted next to each ID column with all values replaced with NA except the maximums and minimums. Both of which were calculated in the smoothing code above. For example, this is what I need the final dataframe to look like :

```
 Date  59231   59231_Max   59231_Min  158157   158157_Max   158157_Min  282302    282302_Max    282302_Min
13149     NA          NA          NA   0.398           NA           NA      NA            NA            NA
13157  0.344          NA          NA   0.267           NA           NA   0.327            NA            NA
13165     NA          NA          NA   0.431           NA           NA      NA            NA            NA
13173  0.398          NA          NA      NA           NA           NA   0.282            NA            NA
13181     NA          NA          NA   0.360           NA           NA   0.260            NA            NA
13189  0.587          NA          NA   0.434           NA           NA   0.293            NA         0.293
13197     NA          NA          NA   0.434           NA           NA    0.25            NA            NA
13205     NA          NA          NA   0.465           NA           NA   0.288            NA            NA
13213  0.451          NA          NA   0.447           NA           NA   0.336            NA            NA
13221  0.597          NA          NA   0.521           NA           NA   0.299         0.299            NA
  ...    ...          ..          ..     ...           ..           ..     ...           ...            ..
```

This is what it looks like right now.

```
 Date  59231   59231_Max   59231_Min     Date  158157   158157_Max   158157_Min    Date  282302    282302_Max    282302_Min
13157  0.344       0.593       0.386    13149   0.398        0.595        0.533   13157   0.327         0.299         0.293
13173  0.398       0.425       0.282    13157   0.267        0.546        0.508   13173   0.282         0.331         0.255
13189  0.587       0.315       0.297    13165   0.431        0.545        0.539   13181   0.260            NA         0.285
13213  0.451       0.322       0.273    13181   0.360        0.530        0.320   13189   0.293            NA            NA
13221  0.597       0.653          NA    13189   0.434           NA           NA   13197   0.250            NA            NA
13229  0.593          NA          NA    13197   0.434           NA           NA   13205   0.288            NA            NA
13237  0.556          NA          NA    13205   0.465           NA           NA   13213   0.336            NA            NA
13245  0.559          NA          NA    13213   0.447           NA           NA   13221   0.299            NA            NA
13253  0.375          NA          NA    13221   0.521           NA           NA   13229   0.290            NA            NA
13261  0.374          NA          NA    13229   0.539           NA           NA   13237   0.280            NA            NA
.....    ...          ..          ..    .....   .....           ..           ..   .....   .....           ...            ..
```

Note: I had to omit NAs during each loop so the code produces a CSV file with a unique subset date column for each ID. I would love to just have one date column like the ideal table above.

In my code I started to create a new data frame and appending each column after each loop but I can't figure out how to match up the maxs and mins in the right cells. Right now all the max and mins are stacked at the top of their columns. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What format are the dates in? e.g. `13149`

Comment: They're days since 01/01/1980

Answer (score 0):

How about this? It adds the min and max columns.

```
df
df$max <- apply(df[2:4], 1, max, na.rm = TRUE)
df$min <- apply(df[2:4], 1, min, na.rm = TRUE)
head(df)
```

Which produces:

```
     ID X59231 X158157 X282302   max   min
1 13149     NA   0.398      NA 0.398 0.398
2 13157  0.344   0.267   0.327 0.344 0.267
3 13165     NA   0.431      NA 0.431 0.431
4 13173  0.398      NA   0.282 0.398 0.282
5 13181     NA   0.360   0.260 0.360 0.260
6 13189  0.587   0.434   0.293 0.587 0.293
```

I have added this based on the clarification that you have provided. You can ignore the bit above:

This will produce what you want. I have only done it for the first column, but you can just change the variables to get the other columns.

```
library(dplyr)
df2 <- as_tibble(df)
df2 <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(X59231_min = min(X59231, na.rm = TRUE))%>% 
  mutate(X59231_min = ifelse(X59231 == X59231_min, X59231_min, NA)) %>% 
  mutate(X59231_max = max(X59231, na.rm = TRUE))%>% 
  mutate(X59231_max = ifelse(X59231 == X59231_max, X59231_max, NA))
```

So:

`df2 %>% filter(!is.na(X59231_min))`

gives us:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 6
     ID X59231 X158157 X282302 X59231_min X59231_max
  <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 13349  0.271    0.51   0.284      0.271         NA
```

And:

`df2 %>% filter(!is.na(X59231_max))`

Shows:

```
# A tibble: 1 x 6
     ID X59231 X158157 X282302 X59231_min X59231_max
  <int>  <dbl>   <dbl>   <dbl>      <dbl>      <dbl>
1 13493  0.666      NA      NA         NA      0.666
```

You should be able to do it for the other columns.

Comment: It looks a bit different to your example, but it sounds like what you are after by your description.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. The code is actually calculating the maxs and mins for each column not row that's why I needed two new columns for each ID. I edited the post to clarify

Comment: I have added to the response. I think this will do what you want.

Comment: Yeah I still think I'm not explaining it correctly. The max and mins have alreayd been calculated in the code. I just need help putting them in the right cells to match up with their dates. So say I have a max of 0.9 on January 15th, right now my code is sticking that 0.9 in the first cell of the new _Max column which is January 1st. Not January 15th where it should be. I updated more of my post to clarify further. Sorry.

Comment: Doesn't my code do that? If you run the full code and not the filtered versions?